# Finding a $t$ for which three vectors are linearly dependent

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> Find a $t \in \mathbb{R}$ so that $(3,1,4)$, $(2,-3,5)$ and $(5,9,t)$ are linearly dependent.

I know how to solve for $t$, but the approach didn't seem very systematic to me. Instead of finding $a_1, a_2, a_3$, not all $0$, such that $a_1(3,1,4) + a_2(2,-3,5) + a_3 (5,9,t) = 0$, I set up
$$
a(3,1,4) + b(2,-3,5) = (5,9,t)
$$
for $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. Then
$$
(3a + 2b, a - 3b, 4a + 5b) = (5,9,t),
$$
so we extract the system of equations
\begin{align*}
3a + 2b & = 5 \\ 
a - 3b & = 9 \\ 
4a + 5b & = t. 
\end{align*}
Solving the first two equations, we get $a = 3$, $b = -2$. Plugging into the third equation, we get $t = 2$.

---

My only explanation for why I did this is "because it worked" and allowed me to avoid computing or row-reducing with $t$ directly. I think this guarantees that these three equations are consistent because $a$ and $b$ are determined by the first two equations, and I can select $t$ to force them to satisfy the third.

Could someone help me understand the sequencing of steps? The first thing I would have done if given the problem without having tried anything is to select $a_1, a_2, a_3$ as above and try to row-reduce, but that's quite messy (and not covered at this point in Axler's book). I'd like to have a better intuitive understanding than this than "because it works."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, what you seem to be exploiting here is Axler's Linear Dependence Lemma:

> A list of vectors $(v_1, \ldots, v_n)$ is linearly dependent if and only if some $v_i \in \operatorname{span}(v_1, \ldots, v_{i-1})$.

It's not difficult to see that $(3, 1, 4)$ and $(2, -3, 5)$ are linearly independent, as neither is a scalar multiple of the other. So, if we add a third vector $(5, 9, t)$ to the list, it will form a linearly dependent list if and only if it is a linear combination of the other two.

This is what you're checking here. By making the system consistent, you are guaranteeing a linear combination of $(3, 1, 4)$ and $(2, -3, 5)$ that produces $(5, 9, t)$. If you can form such a linear combination (i.e. if the system is consistent), then you have linear dependence. If not, then you have linear independence.

Answer (score 1):

Theo's answer perfectly justifies why your method works. However since you mentioned that you want to reduce computation and row reducing, you might be interested in [Cramer's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule).

So it follows that the system of equation

$a_1(3,1,4) + a_2(2,-3,5) + a_3 (5,9,t) = 0$ will have a non-zero solution if the determinant is $0$. If the determinant is $0$ then it will have a unique solution , i.e $a_{1}=a_{2}=a_{3}=0$ which would imply linear independence.

So it suffices to just find $t$ such that :-

$$\begin{vmatrix} 3&1&4\\2&-3&5\\ 5&9&t\end{vmatrix}=0$$

Answer (score 1):

For a more intuitive understanding of linear (in)dependence, please see my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4318177/i-cant-understand-a-definition-and-a-theorem-about-vector-spaces-and-linear-in/4318233#4318233).

It’s also useful to think about the geometry of the problem. As $t$ varies, the points $(5,9,t)$ trace out a line. In fact it’s a line parallel to the $z$-axis. The vectors that are linear combinations of $(3,1,4)$ and $(2,-3,5)$ form a plane. Essentially what you’re doing is finding the value of $t$ where the line intersects the plane.

The logic you used makes perfect sense, even though you didn’t use the standard (rather unintuitive) definition of linear independence.